# Put break in function c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a switch statement:

```
swtich(x)
{
    case 1:
           ...
           break;
    case 2:
           ...
           break;
}
```

I want to put the `...` code in a function but I want to put the break too... So I want something like that

```
void func()
{
     ...;
     break;
}

swtich(x)
{
    case 1:
           func();
    case 2:
           func();
}
```

Break gives error (I know why) but what I can do?

Comment: Just put the break after the call to `func()` in your switch

Comment: In this case, `break` acts as terminator to each case of the `switch` statement. You don't have to put it into the function. It should remain at the end of each `case ...` block.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to know if it possible

Comment: Just throw an exception! </kidding>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Best you can do is:

```
swtich(x)
{
    case 1:
           func();
           break;
    case 2:
           func();
           break;
}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/adbctzc4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for a discussion of what break is for:

> The break statement terminates the closest enclosing loop or switch statement in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that follows the terminated statement, if any.

If you put it in a function, how will it know which loop or switch statement it's supposed to apply to?

Comment: @Loclip: Not sure how it could be much simpler.

Comment: If what I wanted be possible then it would be simpler :D

Comment: @Loclip: I think you are missing what a headache it would be if you really could do what you are proposing. What do you do with a `break` statement in a function if the function wasn't called from a loop or a switch?

Comment: Expanding on Matt's point, even worse still, imagine if any unknown function you called had the potential of breaking you out of a loop you were in without you knowing about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put the `break` in another method.

Though if you want `case 1` and `case 2` to do the same thing, this is legal:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        func();
        break;
}
```

Comment: You have point here but my function have parameters... I just wanted to know if I could do what I say..

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it's not possible. Look at it this way, what would be the expected behavior be if you were not inside a switch statement when the execution gets to the `break;` line?

Put the `break;` statement after the function call. If you want the function to stop execution under a given condition, use the `return;` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the break in the function. Plain and simple.

```
switch(x)
{
    case 1:
           func();
           break;
    case 2:
           func();
           break;
}
```